# how to format code to avoid warnings - Vue

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm working on my first Vue project in the company that I work. I have noticed when I run the project I get warnings that they have be fixed using `--fix` all the warnings are related with indentation, spaces, new lines and things like that. Is there a formatter for Vue? I was using the default VS Code format on save but didn't help with the warnings.

Comment: [https://eslint.vuejs.org/](https://eslint.vuejs.org/)

Comment: @DavidWeldon thank you. Feel free to put it as an answer to get the poitns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, the gold standard for linting JavaScript is [eslint](https://eslint.org/). For Vue, you can use [eslint-plugin-vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/).

The [user guide](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#user-guide) will walk you through how to install and configure, and how to integrate it into your editor.